# Possible circular reference in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with circular dependency when I need to SAVE a 'document'.

My application is all Restfull with the interface via AngularJS.

On the screen to create a COMPANY, you can create OBJECTS and SERVICES. In the creation of the SERVICES screen, it must associate a created OBJECT.

**The problem is that the OBJECT created has not yet persisted, so I don't have a _id.** Thus it is not possible to reference it in SERVICE. Only when I have an OBJECT persisted, I can associate it in `company.services[0].object`.

Any suggestion?

This is what I need to be saved in MongoDB. Look at the reference to the OBJECT `"5779f75a27f9d259248211c7"` in SERVICE.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5749bb92bf8145c97988e4a9"),
    "name" : "company 1",
    "services" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5764cb2c00d00cf10c9c41c6"),
            "description" : "service 1",
            "object" : ObjectId("5779f75a27f9d259248211c7"),
        }
    ],
    "objects" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5779f75a27f9d259248211c7"),
            "description" : "object 1",
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my Schema:

```
var objectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Description is required'
  }
})

var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Description is required'
  },
  object: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Object'
  },
})

var companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Name is required'
  },
  guarda_documentos: {
    services: [serviceSchema],
    objects: [objectSchema],
  },
});

mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
mongoose.model('Object', objectSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to persist your object first and once this is done, use the returned `_id` to then persist your service. This is an async process.

```
// Simplified code concept

// Create a new object
var o = new Object()
o.description = 'foo'
...

// Create a new service
var s = new Service()

// Save object and return it (will now have an _id)
o.save(function(err, doc) {

  // Add object reference to service and save
  s.object = doc._id
  s.save(function(err, res) {
    // Call your controller or whatever callback here
  })
})
```

On another note don't use "Object" as the name of your doc. It already defined in Javascript.

Comment: The problem is that Service and Object are sub-document of Company.

Comment: Since your objects are references in services why do you have it as a sub document of company. Unless it has another purpose then described here then remove the object subdoc from company. Then follow the same process of async: object save -> service save -> company save